# Account Linking Alexa with Twitter - Amazon Echo

Tags: twitter, passport.js, alexa-skills-kit, passport-twitter, amazon-echo

As of now I cannot seem to get my Alexa skill linked with twitter.  Currently, I have a node/express server running on EBS which, I am using [passport-twitter](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter) to handle the oauth part of the authentication.  Right now my flow is such:

1. Enable skill in Alexa app
2. Click 'sign in to account' in alexa app
3. Twitter Login screen is displayed and I enter user name and password then click Login button
4. get redirected to Amazon provided url for callback once authenticated and get an 'Unable to link you skill'.

I login and everything, so I think issue is with redirection, which is defined in the twitter auth callback on my express server like so:

```
app.get('/auth/twitter/callback',
passport.authenticate('twitter', {failureRedirect: '/login'}),
function(req, res){

  var redirectUrl= 'https://pitangui.amazon.com/spa/skill/account-linking-status.html?vendorId=M28J2SR508CPU9#state='
  +state+'&access_token='+myToken+'&token_type=Bearer';

  res.redirect(302, redirectUrl);
});
```

My redirect url, minus the sensitive data, is 
https://pitangui.amazon.com/spa/skill/account-linking-status.html?vendorId=M28J2SR5BLAH#state=&access_token=&token_type=Bearer

Any ideas on how to debug/troubleshoot as well as any suggestions to fix issue would be awesomely appreciated.

Comment: Might be related: https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/540/using-amazon-lwa-to-connect-custom-alexa-skill-fails

Answer (score 0):

You have a hash ('#') before the 'state' URL parameter.  Perhaps you meant for that to be an ampersand ('&')?

https://pitangui.amazon.com/spa/skill/account-linking-status.html?vendorId=M28J2SR5BLAH&state=&access_token=&token_type=Bearer